# It is based on set theory. Here I wan to know that how can I derive the modulus of P(A) is equal to 2ⁿ.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

How to proof /P(A)/=2ⁿ
/ / For modulus sign
A: Given set
P(A):Power of set A
2ⁿ: The number of possible elements.
Hints: In the question it says that to prove it by induction method .  /P(A)/=2ⁿ is possible when set A has 'n' number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction on $n$. Let $P(n)$ be the sentence $P(n)=(|A|=n\Rightarrow |\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^n)$. Then $P(1)=(|A|=1\Rightarrow |\mathcal{P}(A)|=2)$, which is true, because if $|A|=1$ then $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\varnothing, A\}$. Let now $|A|=n+1$. Let $x\in A$. Consider the set $A'=A-\{x\}$. Counting the subsets of $A$, we have all the subsets of $A'$ and all the subsets of $A'$ with $x$ added to them, hence in total $2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$ subsets.